# Problem with referencing Castle.ActiveRecord.dll

Tags: c#, .net, castle-activerecord

I downloaded recent sources of Castle.ActiveRecord from github. I succesfully compiled it against vs2010 (targetting .Net 4.0)

I added reference to **Castle.Core**, **Castle.ActiveRecord.dll** assembly and **using Castle.ActiveRecord;** to my simple project (Console app, .Net 4.0)

And i got the following compile error
"The type or namespace name 'ActiveRecord' does not exist in the namespace 'Castle' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

But this namespace exists in this assembly (I checked via object browser)

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Castle.Core and Castle.ActiveRecord both have a dependency on System.Web. System.Web does not exist in the .NET Client Profile (either 3.5 or 4). Look further down in your compile errors/warnings and you'll see:

> The referenced assembly "Castle.Core"
>   could not be resolved because it has a
>   dependency on "System.Web,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which
>   is not in the currently targeted framework
>   ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client".
>   Please remove references to assemblies
>   not in the targeted framework or
>   consider retargeting your project.

Go to Project Properties... Application... Target framework... and switch it to ".NET Framework 4" and you should be good.

Comment: Thanks. My project was targetting "Net Framewrk 4.0 Client profile". I dont understand difference between "Net Framewrk 4.0 Client profile" and "Net Framewrk 4.0". This mismatch was a problem.

Comment: The Client Profile is a stripped down version of the .NET Framework that only includes namespaces/classes required for desktop apps. So it has the code for WPF, WinForms, System.Collections, ..., but omits server-side components like ASP.NET. It makes for a quicker install experience for most end users and is easily upgradeable to the full .NET Framework if required later. Just an option that Microsoft starting offering with .NET 3.5 SP1...